# Running a powershell script which resides on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

We have a powershell script which is on our server. Trying to figure out how to use Invoke-Command with the -ComputerName to run it remotely, but when I run:

```
Invoke-Command - ComputerName XXXX -FilePath YYYY
```

It appears that Invoke-Command is looking for a local file. How do I specify that I want to remotely run a script which is only available on the remote machine?

Comment: Do you mean if it's on a network share? if so try -Authenication Credssp when you PSSession. This allows for a double hop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-ScriptBlock` parameter along with [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName machine1 -Scriptblock {
    . "C:\path\to\file.ps1"
}
```

Edit: adding a version that uses creds

```
# Will bring up a dialogue box asking for credentials
$creds = get-credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName machine1 -Credential $creds -Scriptblock {
    . "C:\path\to\file.ps1"
}
```

Comment: How do you add username/password credentials?